# How to get text of selected <Dropdown/> option in ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

I am working on a ReactJS application and I am trying to get the **text** of a selected option in a dropdown (Semantic UI component);

```
exposedCampaignOnChange = (e, {value}) => {
    this.props.campaignExposedSelected(value);
};

<Dropdown
    placeholder='Campaign Exposed To'
    fluid
    search
    selection
    multiple
    options={this.state.campaigns}
    onChange={this.exposedCampaignOnChange}
/>
```

The above code returns the **value**. `this.state.campaigns` is made up of an array of objects with `value` and `text` properties. In addition to the `value`, I also want to get the `text`value of the selected options.

Appreciate any guidance on the matter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use synthetic event's target property to get the text like:

```
exposedCampaignOnChange = (e, {value}) => {
  e.persist();
  console.log(e.target.textContent);
  this.props.campaignExposedSelected(value);
};

<Dropdown
  placeholder='Campaign Exposed To'
  fluid
  search
  selection
  multiple
  options={this.state.campaigns}
  onChange={this.exposedCampaignOnChange}
/>
```

Comment: Better not `target`, but `currentTarget`: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/11508#issuecomment-256045682

Comment: e.taget.innerHTML worked for me too as the output of the dropdown option was a div > span > text

Answer (score 1):

Semantic ui react Dropdown `onChange` event takes two arguments - 
`onChange(event: SyntheticEvent, data: object)`. You don't need to pass them explicitly while calling the function.

```
exposedCampaignOnChange = (e, value) => {
  e.persist();
  this.props.campaignExposedSelected(value);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

data/value should have selected option text like in semantic UI

```
function getSelectedTextValue() {
  alert( $('.ui.dropdown').dropdown('get text') + " : " + $('.ui.dropdown').dropdown('get value') );
}
```